# JQuery - Have Loading Dialog Appear Every Time an Item is Selected (When Needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading

So the problem is that I have a loading dialog that sometimes doesn't execute when there's a soft refresh (information gets updated/changed but page hasn't refreshed).  Mostly it appears fine on pages having forms and tables, but not always.

The tables especially display a lot of information depending on which item is chosen from the dropdown menu.  What I've noticed is that the loading dialog will show when clicking to a new page or refreshing the current page, yay, but due to our site not having unique URLs for every page/application (boo), there's trouble when you want to click something else in the dropdown list, but have to wait for everything to load with nothing telling you it's loading.  When it comes to the forms and tables, users can change or add things and having the loading mechanism focuses on the dialog and prevents them from doing anything before everything loads (goal).

In HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Loading..." style="display:none">
    <br />
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Javascript script tags:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('.ng-isolate-scope>ul').addClass('col-md-2')
        //$('.tab-pane').addClass('col-md-10')

        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fade",
            hide: "fade",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: [
            ],
            open: function (event, ui) {
                //$('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
                $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
            },
            close: function () {

            }
        });

    });
```

What exactly is the problem here?  I'm getting inconsistent results (sometimes it shows loading, sometimes it doesn't).  I have a feeling it's has to do with the URLs and page navigation.

I've tried commenting out bits of the last function and just leaving the first two only.  The Javascript works in the Index (main page of one of the Views), but not elsewhere in the Views.

**Edit**

I understand what the issue is more, but I'm still confused.  So I'm using a MVC framework and originally I wanted to copy the code snippets above into the pages that needed a loading dialog.  I don't think that will work well.  The only page in that site section that loads well doesn't have the codes in its own HTML file, rather all the pages I'm looking at are nested within the main Index and that's why Index only has the code from above.  I believe this comes to a question concerning scope or similar since all of these pages rely on Index for the basic structure (which includes popping a loading screen), but for some reason this isn't happening, any suggestions/answers?

Comment: I'd suggest using ajaxStart and ajaxStop, to avoid closing the dialog early if an ajax request is still pending but another completes.

Comment: `.ng-isolate-scope>ul` Is this jquery mixed into an angularjs app? if so, is it integrated into it properly in such a way that the jQuery code will play nicely with the digest cycle?

Comment: I'll try that.  I find it weird because it's consistently working in other pages that also has a lot of content so I figured copying and pasting the same into the pages without would work.  Yes, there's about 6 pages I'm editing that contains HTML with Javascript, JQuery, AngularJS, and CSS in them plus their controllers with JQuery, Javascript, and AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, just had to make sure I call the function to display the loading dialog every place that needed it.  Simple solution that took me forever to get.

So I would place:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

...any place that had the forms/tables that needed time to populate values, i.e. before the function that grabbed the information from the database, and placed this after that same function normally:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

That was it pretty much.  All the application took the main structure from the Index page so I didn't need to copy and paste all the styling and HTML into every page.